# Fedora is taking over 8gb ram, is this normal?

Tags: linux, memory, fedora

I've been using fedora for some time now but I'm completly newbie in linux SO.
For the past mounths my notebook just started to lag when I open chrome, slack and visual studio simultaneously. The strange part is that while it's not the best, my notebook still very good hardware.

- I7 11800h
- RTX 3050
- 16gb ram

Today I booted my notebook and notice that the memory usage is quite high. There was nothing open and the memory consumption was already at 7gb

Do anybody knows what is causing this issue? How can I improve this question?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Note that most of the used RAM is buffered/cached. Suggest you read up on what this means.

Comment: It's doesn't seem exceptionally high. The "used" memory is just 2.8G, with 12G available.

Comment: It looks like your package manager is using some memory, perhaps doing a system update, but aside from that as mentioned by Tom and Darren it doesn't seem to be actually using any significant amount of RAM for anything except the cache which is the "buffer" figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operating system (OS) reallocates RAM as needed, and even if almost all were used with no application running, that is *not* an issue.

However, programming environments such as Visual Studio, and browsers such as Chrome (particularly with multiple tabs open!), may use *so* much RAM that some memory has to be moved to a swap file on SSD or HDD, which *s l o w s* down the machine.

- Check if there are [background services (daemons) running at startup](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-list-startup-services-at-boot-time-in-fedora-linux/) that are unneeded. Use the [Startup Applications](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Fedora_Desktop_-_Starting_Applications_on_Login) GUI to see what is running at startup.
- *Close some applications or browser tabs*, get a faster SSD (for the sake of the swap file), or get additional RAM (though 16 GB shold be sufficient for your current usage).

Comment: I think this is too general an explanation. OP has lots of cached memory, common on modern operating systems. Also as common are misconceptions about what “free” means.